# SANE stack start server programmatically

Tags: javascript, ember.js, deployment, sails.js

How do you do `sane up` programmatically?

I believe `sane-cli/bin/sane.js` is the file being executed when I use the `sane` command.  How do I pass `up` to that file programmatically?

Also, I believe `sane.js` calls `sane-cli/lib/cli.js` at some point and passes it the `up` command.  So may be I may have to to programmatically pass `up` to `cli.js`.

Either way, any help with this would be greatly appreciated.